# Exercise: implementing Stream in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am following the book `Functional programming in Scala` and in particular the section where you implement a simple Stream trait and companion object. For reference, here is what we have so far in the companion obejct

```
object Stream {
  def empty[A]: Stream[A] =
    new Stream[A] {
      def uncons = None
    }

  def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] =
    new Stream[A] {
      lazy val uncons = Some((hd, tl))
    }

  def apply[A](as: A*): Stream[A] =
    if (as.isEmpty)
      empty
    else
      cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
}
```

and the trait so far:

```
trait Stream[A] {
  import Stream._

  def uncons: Option[(A, Stream[A])]

  def toList: List[A] = uncons match {
    case None => Nil: List[A]
    case Some((a, as)) => a :: as.toList
  }

  def #::(a: => A) = cons(a, this)

  def take(n: Int): Stream[A] =
    if (n <= 0)
      empty
    else (
      uncons
      map { case (a, as) => a #:: (as take (n - 1)) }
      getOrElse empty
    )
}
```

The next exercise requires me to write an implementation for `takeWhile` and I thought the following would do

```
  def takeWhile(f: A => Boolean): Stream[A] = (
    uncons
    map { case (a, as) => if (f(a)) (a #:: (as takeWhile f)) else empty }
    getOrElse empty
  )
```

Unfortunately, is seems that I get a variance error that I am not able to track down:

```
error: type mismatch;  found   : Stream[_2] where type _2 <: A 
required: Stream[A]
Note: _2 <: A, but trait Stream is invariant in type A.
You may wish to define A as +A instead. (SLS 4.5)
           getOrElse empty
           ^
```

I could add a variance annotation, but before doing that I would like to understand what is going wrong here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seems to be an issue with type inference, because it works if you explicitly specify the type of the subexpression `uncons map { case (a, as) => if (f(a)) (a #:: (as takeWhile f)) else empty }`.

```
def takeWhile(f: A => Boolean): Stream[A] = {
  val mapped:Option[Stream[A]] = uncons map {
    case (a, as) => if (f(a)) (a #:: (as takeWhile f)) else empty
  }
  mapped getOrElse empty
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Do you have any clue why the type inferencer is failing in this case? Is it common in Scala to have to type intermediate values (except, of course, for ambiguous cases like `Nil: List[Int]`)?

Comment: I don't know why it fails, but it is not common. There are some known limitations though, for instance with recursive functions or multiple returns. Maybe you should ask about this issue on the mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

To complete a bit the other answer, the `empty` on this line:

```
map { case (a, as) => if (f(a)) (a #:: (as takeWhile f)) else empty }
```

is inferred as `empty[Nothing]`, which means that `(a #:: (as takeWhile f)) else empty` is inferred as `Stream[Foo <: A]` and since a `Stream[A]` is expected and `Stream` is invariant, you have an error.

So this gives us the cleanest way to fix this: just annotate `empty`:

```
map { case (a, as) => if (f(a)) (a #:: (as takeWhile f)) else empty[A] }
```

And then it compiles fine.

This does not happen with the original `Stream` because it is covariant, so either you actually want `Stream.empty` to be a `Stream[Nothing]` (just like `Nil` is a `List[Nothing]`), or you don't care.

Now, as to exactly why it is inferred as `empty[Nothing]` and not `empty[A]`, this is probably hidden somewhere in SLS 6.26.4 "Local Type Inference", but this part cannot really be accused of being easy to read...

As a rule a thumb, always be suspicious whenever you call methods:

- that have type parameters whose only way to infer is the expected return type (usually because they have no arguments),
- AND at the same time the expected return type is itself supposed to be inferred from somewhere else.